# How can I easily parse the returned JSON object for only the information I require?

Tags: c#, json, google-api

Using the following snippet of code, I can get 4 results from the google Web Search API.  I know I'm using a deprecated API, but I'm only testing something here and will use the new Custom Search API when I'm more familiar with it.  For now, though, I was wondering how I can parse the returned result for the "unescapedUrl" that is in the result?  Basically, I want to grab all four of the "unescapedUrl" values in the returned JSON.
Here's my code:

```
var searchTerm = "pizza boxes";
        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            web.Headers.Add("Referrer", "http://localhost:49360/");
            var result = web.DownloadString(String.Format(
                   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={0}&rsz=4",
                   searchTerm));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

I don't want to use JSON.Net with this (for now) unless I absolutely have to.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you want to go through a world of pain, you absolutely have to use a JSON library like JSON.Net. Why are you so determined to avoid it, anyway?

Comment: I don't have a big reason to avoid it, actually.  I just didn't want to have to download it and try to figure out how to get it to work with Visual Studio.  I'm not very adept with VS and I'm sure I'd probably end up messing something up if I try to add a reference to the new JSON.Net libraries.  Of course, if that's what I have to do then I'll start researching how to do that right away.  I was just hoping that there was a way to deserialize(?) the returned data and just loop through it and grab all unescapedUrl values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a type, but have you thought about using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) from System.Web.Extensions.dll?

I can't say I know the Google API well, but if it's a simple JSON property bag that's returned, you could get away with something as simple as this:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> dict = ser.DeserializeObject(@"{""key"":""value""}") as System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;

Console.WriteLine(dict["key"].ToString());
```

Comment: Heh, actually I have not considered that.  Mainly because of my unfamiliarity with the C# classes (libraries?  Namespaces?).  I will check it out now and see if it will help me.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you've got me on the right track, Laramie.  I was reading some code on another site and it's very similar to what you've posted (in that it uses the JavaScriptSerializer).  I'll dig some more and see what I can come up with, but I think you've helped me find the solution.  Thanks!